# Shaded jar Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]

Tags: spring-data-jpa, classpath, maven-shade-plugin

I am getting above exception in my web application running in Tomcat when packaged all my dependencies including spring-data-jpa.jar in a single jar using maven-shaded-plugin and put under WEB-INF/lib directory.

Problem dis-appears if I package the spring-data-jpa.jar directly into WEB-INF/lib along with my shaded jar?

```
NOTE: I will be running the same package as AWS Lambda hence I need to create a shaded jar.
```

Answer (score 1):

To help others, the problem was that multiple spring-*.jar files `META-INF/spring.handlers` files which overwrites each other while running the `maven-shade-plugin`.

To resolve use `<transformers>` in the plugin configuration. My final plugin configuration looks like as follows;

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <!-- Remove signatures from transitive dependencies and append spring handlers and schemas -->
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Above will merge all handlers in one single file in final jar. Enjoy :-)